# Password strength criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a password input field with the following criteria:

- Minimum of 8 characters
- At least 1 number OR special character (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_characters)

I'm using the following:

```
function checkStrength( password ) {
    var min_length = /^[\s\S]{8,}$/,
      number       = /[0-9]/,
      special      = /[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`´{|}~]/;

    if( min_length.test( password ) && (number.test( password ) || special.test( password )) ){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I guess my question is whether there is a way to combine the regular expressions, or if my expressions are faulty.

Comment: It is not faulty but it can be combined in a single regex

Comment: I think its better to check the length without using regex.

Comment: Minimum 10 characters?  Jeez.

Comment: actually 10 is not enough, you need 13 to be safe from private attackers.

Comment: I always hate these sorts of arbitrary password rules. I'd like to see more password strength restrictions based on how long it would actually take to brute-force, like this: https://howsecureismypassword.net/ (it's a little more difficult to make but is both more permissive and more secure if given a suitable threshold)

Comment: Anyway for the sake of learning regex, if you want to combine those rules you should look into lookaheads / lookbehinds. Simply merge your number & special rules (since they're OR anyway) and use a lookahead to check for the characters while using the base regex to check the length (or vice-versa). It's a very inefficient way of accomplishing this task though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex you could use.

Note that in the delimiter form `/.../` the delimiter character `/` must be
escaped `\/` in the regex if it is anywhere in the regex
(*there  is one in your character class*).

```
#  /^(?=.{8})(?=.*(?:\d|[\\!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`´{|}~]))/

 ^                     # Beginning of string
 (?= .{8} )            # Lookahead for at least 8 characters
 (?=                   # Lookahead
      .*                    # 0 to many, any character, to get to one of the following
      (?:
           \d                    # A digit
        |                      # or,
           [\\!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`´{|}~]   # A special character
      )
 )
 # Because we were just looking ahead, we are still
 # at the beginning of the string here.
 # Optionally match the entire line.
 # .+ $
```

Additionally, *Digit* and *Special Character* can be combined into a single class.

```
 # /^(?=.{8})(?=.*[\d\\!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`´{|}~])/

   # Beginning of string
 ^ 
   # Lookahead for at least 8 characters
 (?= .{8} )
   # Lookahead for a digit OR a special character
 (?= .* [\d\\!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`´{|}~] )
   # Optionally match the entire line.
   # .+ $
```

Comment: Help me understand what I am missing here AFA `.*`.  At first it seems unnecessary in the second lookahead to me, but several tests that should pass fail without it.

Comment: @J0e3gan - Could you expand what you mean by "`.*` seem unnecessary".